# Ignore offline computers in Get-ADComputer

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to do run Get-WmiObject / Get-CimInstance cmdlets on every online computers from my domain, I've tought of doing something like this :

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Foreeach-Object {
#Do Something
}
```

The problem is that if the computer isn't online I'll get an error, and as far as i'm aware I can't run that command for online computers only.

So I was thinking about going on the next computer when an error occurs, using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` but it would just execute the rest of the code inside the loop anyways and I want to avoid that.

Is there any way to get outside of the loop in my situation when that occurs or any other way I could do what I need ?

Thank you !

Comment: Use Where-Object to filter out the null entries.

Comment: Do in parallel `get-ciminstance -computername computer1,computer2,computer3` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powershell 5.1, you can get a list of online computers quickly like this (responsetime and address are the actual properties):

```
if (! (test-path list.txt)) { Get-ADComputer -Filter * | % name |
  set-content list.txt }
$list = get-content list.txt
$uplist = test-connection -count 1 $list -AsJob | receive-job -wait -auto | 
  ? responsetime | % address
$uplist | Foreeach-Object {
  #Do Something with $_
}
# or in parallel:
# invoke-command $uplist { 'whatever' }
```

Comment: Thank you, used it with an if statement and works perfectly ! `if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet) { }`

Comment: @Wayne What do you think of this edit?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Test-Connection` to test whether you can connect to the remote machine, then `return` from the `ForEach-Object` block if you can't:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" |ForEach-Object {
  # pick host name
  if(-not($cn = $_.DNSHostName)) {
    $cn = $_.Name
  }

  # test connectivity - change to `-Protocol DCOM` for Get-WmiObject
  if(-not(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.DNSHostName -Protocol WSMan -Quiet)) {
    return
  }

  Get-CimInstance ... -ComputerName $cn
}
```